# Where to find my.ini for Worklight server

Tags: mysql, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

I am setting up a worklight server and have followed the steps given in the IBM site. I am now setting up my database using MySQL. And in this [link](https://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc%2Fadmin%2Ft_configuring_Apache_Tomcat_manually.html), it said to update the option file. I am not familiar with the option file, but based on research, it is the my.ini file. However, I was not able to locate the file. Anyone knows where I can find this file? thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The my.ini file is a MySQL options file; it has zero relation to Worklight Server.

The fact you're setting up MySQL as the Worklight Server database, does not mean there is a my.ini file *for Worklight Server*.
So, you need to find the my.ini file *for your MySQL installation*.

You did not state your MySQL version nor your Operating System, so my suggestion is to search google for

```
 my.ini location <your os> mysql <your-mysql-version>
```

For example, in Windows for MySQL 5.5 the location would be: `%PROGRAMDATA%\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\my.ini`

See here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/option-files.html and search for similar based on what you need.